# How can I add a role in code, Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, role

I'm using jboss 4.2.3 and jaas `org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule`.

After a user is logged in I want to add a role to it. How can I do it?

For example, the user clicks in a button and a role is added...

Clarification:
I have 1 app where a user does the login. In the login the users gets some roles (from the db). After that I want to add another roles to the user in my code. My example is: after the user is logged in, he can click a button and in my servlet a new role is added to the user.

It seems Jboss doesn't allow this, roles can be accessed only in the login module.

Comment: Can you clarify?  do you want an application to be able to modify another apps security roles or you want to change the current users role (ala sudo)?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for an answer to this problem, and I found that JBoss lets you flush the Credential Cache, programmatically and also by using a MBean:

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/CachingLoginCredentials

You can add the role to the user and then cause that user's credentials to be flushed.  As far as I can tell, they have to log out and then log back in to your application; after that happens, they'll have the new role that you gave them.

If there is a way to assign the role without requiring the user to log out and back in, I'd like to hear about it.